# SQL "violate foreign key constraint" error message

Tags: sql, database, postgresql

I keep getting this error when I try to delete a comment. I have tried to work around this by dropping all child tables (ie. the commenter table that is mentioned in the error message) and currently just have 2 separate tables with no references or foreign keys. But the same error message comes up. What am I doing wrong?

SQL:

```
CREATE TABLE fac_members (
  id serial primary key,
  firstname varchar(255) NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE comments (
  id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
  text_content TEXT
);
```

JS:

```js
server.post('/delete-comment', (request, response) => {
  const commentToDelete = [request.body.name];
  console.log(commentToDelete) //eg. "Ko is kind and funny"
  return db
    .query(`DELETE FROM comments WHERE text_content = $1;`, commentToDelete)
    .then(() => {
      response.redirect("/comments");
    })
})
```

Error message:

```
UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: error: update or delete on table "comments" violates foreign key constraint "commenter_commenter_id_fkey" on table "commenter"
```

Comment: The table "commenter" (that you don't show) has row(s) that have reference to the row you want to delete on the table "comments" and, thus, the latter cannot be deleted. Either you delete the references first, and then the main row, or you add a "cascade referential action" to act automatically for you.

Comment: How do I delete the references if I have already deleted the "commenter" entire table? When I try to select the commenter table, it no longer exists... (to clarify, the commenter table is where the reference was)

Comment: Please include the definition of the constraint "commenter_commenter_id_fkey". Clearly your delete operation is trying to violate it.

Comment: Sorry, what do you mean by definition? You mean the entire error message?

Comment: The definition is part of the DDL, usually included in the `CREATE TABLE` statement.

Comment: Sorry, not sure what DDL is... my CREATE TABLE is literally the above code

Comment: Please add the `CREATE TABLE` statement for the table "commenter". That's where the contraint is.

Comment: You mean add it to the init.sql? I have done that now. But I don't think it changes anything? Sorry I am very new to SQL

Comment: Can I just add that it seems strange you are deleting from the "comments" table using only the comment text as the criteria ..... so let's say someone wants to delete their comment that says "OK" - you are then going to delete EVERY comment record from your table with "text_content" = "OK"?  Is that what you expect to happen?

Comment: Yes it's just a basic test I am trying to do to get practice. I am very beginner